# Explain the meaning of $\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t)dt=b'(x)f(b(x))-a'(x)f(a(x))$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

What's the meaning of formula

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t)dt=b'(x)f(b(x))-a'(x)f(a(x))$$

It's similar to Newton-Leibniz formula:

$$\int_a^b f(x) dx = F(b) - F(a)$$

But I can't find link between them. Please help

Comment: The link is that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0$.

Comment: But I didn't start partial derivatives yet. I had only theory on Riemann integral

Comment: Then why would you be looking up things like Newton-Leibniz formula?!  I kind of assume you would know such things if you mention them in your post lol

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Meaning of the formula? What does this mean? What do you actually want to know?

Comment: I wanted to know how to get it. And answer with chain rule formula gave me that answer

Comment: Yes, chain rule is the way to go, plus the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. So you know how to get the formula after all?

Comment: Yes, I do. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One may just see this as the use of the [chain rule formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule), taking $F$ such that
$$
F'(x)=f(x),
$$ it gives
$$
\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t)dt=F(b(x))-F(a(x))
$$ and

> $$
> \frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t)dt=b'(x)f(b(x))-a'(x)f(a(x))
> $$

as announced.

Answer (score 1):

This formula shows how the integration area changes with the change of limits depending on some parameter $x$. Think about it in the following simplified way. You change (say increase) your parameter $x$ by some small amount $\Delta x \to 0$. What will happen? The limits will change (because this is the only part which depends on $x$).

First, let's look at the upper limit $b(x)$. Its derivative $b'(x)$ describes the change which happened, wlog assume that $b(x)$ is increasing in $x$ - then your upper boundary of integration moves to the right, adding an additional bar of area. The width of this additional bar is $b'(x) \Delta x$, its height is $f(b(x))$ - taken at $b(x)$, thus you add area $b'(x) f(b(x)) \Delta x$ - and this is what the first term means (note that to get the derivative you need to divide by $\Delta x$ and take the limit). The second term is connected to change in the lower limit, can be analyzed in similar simplified fashion.